# Can anybody help me improve this speech-to-text code or suggest a more accurate method for speech-to-text dictation?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, richtextbox, speech-recognition

I'm using the following code to input text to a richTextBox via microphone:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ready to talk?", "Speak", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = result.Text;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not recognize input from default audio device. Is a microphone or sound card available?", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();


        }
```

However, the results are not very accurate. I would like to implement a fairly accurate speech-to-text dictation service within my application. Does anybody know a way that I can improve this code, or know of any other methods to implement speech-to-text?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short of actually interpreting the voice with your own code, this is the .NET implementation. If anything, buy a better microphone.

Comment: Are there any third-party solutions that you can recommend? This is an application that I plan to upload to SourceForge. I can't very well tell people to "buy a better mic".

Comment: This question makes a good suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489067/improve-speech-recognition-c-sharp

Comment: You're right about the microphone thing, though. I just plugged my Microsoft Headset in after "training" my PC and it's so much more accurate.

Comment: I'll switch this to an answer so people don't keep reading it. Please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Obvious Answer**

Ultimately, it depends of the quality of sound coming into the program. This depends, almost entirely, on hardware. Improving the hardware means more reliable data. So really, buy a better microphone.

**Training your Computer**

Microsoft PCs has a voice training option, so the computer can 'get used' to your voice. By undergoing this process, the computer will be able to analyse and identify the words you're saying with a much higher degree of accuracy.