# Speech recognition not working well in noise room. how i can improve it?

Tags: c#, voice-recognition

I write code for speech recognition on Visual studio in C#
My Speech Recognition program not working well in noise.
For example when i give voice input it gives output but some times it detects other voices in the room too and give output randomly. Even output not match with my input.
Please help me to improve it. 
Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve Speech Recognition, C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489067/improve-speech-recognition-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Setup the microphone, go to control panel, then ease of access, then speech recognition, then set up microphone. This will base the mic dbz based on your voice.

Once that is done, you can run the program. Most people never set up the microphone. I have done this before and it always helps. Also if your using internal mics on the PC. You will get feedback. I suggest using a USB mic or wireless mic. They usually have noise cancelling technology.

I use them for all my projects using System.Speech. I also recommend turning the dbz down as well.